# How to display iOS apps on iPhone only Standard view

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, iphone-6-plus

I have a problem because if the user enable the option Zoomed:

The application looks different.

How I can fix this?

or **only run the application without zoomed mode**:

only **Standar view**

[image]

The application looks different like this:

[image]

but if the user uses the display zoom "Standard". The application have size correct.

like this:

[image]

Comment: How are you creating and laying out your views?

Comment: I found the problem because de project dont use constrains.